# How to convert sh script into python script

Tags: python-3.x

i have a sh script code and need to convert it into python script.
i m struggling finding the correspondant command.

so here is my sh script

```
RESPONSE=`curl -s -X GET http://192.168.8.1/api/webserver/SesTokInfo`
COOKIE=`echo "$RESPONSE"| grep SessionID=| cut -b 10-147`
TOKEN=`echo "$RESPONSE"| grep TokInfo| cut -b 10-41`


DATA="<request><PageIndex>1</PageIndex><ReadCount>3</ReadCount> 
<BoxType>1</BoxType><SortType>0</SortType><Ascending>0</Ascending> 
<UnreadPreferred>1</UnreadPreferred></request>"

curl -b $COOKIE -c $COOKIE -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" --data 
"$DATA" http://192.168.8.1/api/sms/sms-list --header 
"__RequestVerificationToken: $TOKEN" --header "Content-Type:text/xml"
```

so i m returning the first 3 most recent results of my html page with the different specific tag

i want to write a script in python which can do the same

thanks

Comment: Take a look at the `requests` module: https://pypi.org/project/requests/

Answer (score 0):

Hoping you're aware shell and python are different languages, thus work differently, I hand you [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org), [requests](https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/), and [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

See the quality of your search for solutions to your problem, I think you should be able to achieve what you want.

Comment: thanks for your advices. it almost work with the requests library. i m now just facing some troubles for sending parameters . have you already used it? if yes maybe you can help me in troubleshouting my new code..